# How to remove T and Z in time in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove the `T` and `000Z` in my data:

```
2018-03-20T19:48:12.000Z

2018-07-20T14:33:09.000Z

2018-07-20T14:33:55.000Z
```

I want to get a timestamp that looks like this:

```
2018-03-20 19:48:12

2018-07-20 14:33:09

2018-07-20 14:33:55
```

I tried to format the time using this: NOTE: (OPENEDDATETIME) is the column name.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['OPENEDDATETIME'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

... but I keep getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-03-20T19:48:12.000Z' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y' (match)
```

Comment: Why did you think `2018-03-20T19:48:12.000Z` would match the format `%m/%d/%Y`? Even if you know nothing about strftime-style formats and refuse to read the docs, that's clearly going to mean something kind of month/day/year format, not a year-month-day hour:minute:second.milli format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You datetime format is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"d": ['2018-03-20T19:48:12.000Z', '2018-07-20T14:33:09.000Z', '2018-07-20T14:33:55.000Z']})
df["d"] = pd.to_datetime(df["d"], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                    d
0 2018-03-20 19:48:12
1 2018-07-20 14:33:09
2 2018-07-20 14:33:55
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)**

Comment: that is actually wrong; the format is `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z`. It just so happens that it works correctly here because pandas treats naive datetime as UTC. In vanilla Python, it would be wrong since naive datetime is treated as local time.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove the `T` and `.000Z` from the strings without parsing them as actual `datetime` objects, you can do so with string replacement:

```
>>> date = "2018-03-20T19:48:12.000Z"
>>> date.replace("T", " ").replace(".000Z", "")
'2018-03-20 19:48:12'
```