# Remove +00:00 (UTC offset) from timestamp in Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to remove the `+00:00` from the timestamp below. I used the code below to remove the T and Z from the timestamp but the dtype is still `datetime64[ns, UTC]`  and ideally I would like to convert it to  `datetime64[ns]`

```
df['Timestamp_column'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Timestamp_column before transformation:

```
2020-07-10T14:12:39.000Z
```

Output:

```
2020-07-10 14:12:39+00:00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove T and Z in time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462050/how-to-remove-t-and-z-in-time-in-python)

Comment: I came across that one but didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 6):

you could [`tz_convert` to `None`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656878/10197418):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp_column': ['2020-07-10T14:12:39.000Z']})

df['Timestamp_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp_column']).dt.tz_convert(None)

# df['Timestamp_column']
# 0   2020-07-10 14:12:39
# Name: Timestamp_column, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]:
                       date
0  2020-07-10T14:12:39.000Z

In [51]: df.dtypes
Out[51]:
date    object
dtype: object

In [52]: df["new_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
                       date            new_date
0  2020-07-10T14:12:39.000Z 2020-07-10 14:12:39

In [54]: df.dtypes
Out[54]:
date                object
new_date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: @user12625679 I tested on ipython kernel. It should work fine